# EDIT Control Showing Squares Instead Of Returns

Tags: c, file-io, textbox, windows-ce, pocketc

I'm playing a little bit with [PocketC](http://orbworks.com/pcce) by doing a simple text editor. But with this code to read and to display the contents of the file on the `EDIT` control:

```
int filehandle;
int file_len;
string file_mode;

initComponents()
{
    createctrl("EDIT", "test", 2, 1, 0, 24, 70, 25, TEXTBOX);
    wndshow(TEXTBOX, SW_SHOW);
    guigetfocus();
}

main()
{
    filehandle = fileopen(OpenFileDlg("Plain Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt; All Files (*.*)|*.*"), 0, FILE_READWRITE);
    file_len = filegetlen(filehandle);

    if(filehandle == -1)
    {
        MessageBox("File Could Not Be Found!", "Error", 3, 1);
    }

    initComponents();
    editset(TEXTBOX, fileread(filehandle, file_len));
}
```

It's all ok, but my test file, now have returns:

```
Hello, World!
PocketC
Test Of My Editor
```

Then when I open this file on the editor, instead of returns, I just see two squares(that means that it's a unknown character for that control), but if I change the control to a `STATIC`, it does he returns ok, but I can't edit the text if I use a `STATIC`. Then I want to know what I need to do to do the returns instead of showing those squares.

Also, this field(`EDIT`), is like a `TextField`, I can't do returns on it, then I want to know how to change this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PocketPC, but Windows edit controls need a `ES_MULTILINE` style in order to show multi-line text correctly.

Comment: Did you know the number of this style property at Windows?

Comment: Thanks very much! It works! But where you get this informations about the controls?

Comment: The PocketPC SDK should have header files and documentation.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=83A52AF2-F524-4EC5-9155-717CBE5D25ED&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about PocketC, but in general, you get that behavior if the line break characters used in the data do not match the OS's native line breaks.  For instance, if the data uses CRLF where the OS expects bare CR or bare LF, or vice versa.  Since you are seeing two squares appear, check if the file data is using LFCR, CRCR or LFLF instead of CRLF.

Comment: Remember that I've created the text file using notepad at the device. But how could I know which one is the file using?